# Calculate propagation error

Tags: numeric

How can I calculate the propagation error when I sum many floats. If I for example sum n floats ,how can the error be calculated ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no way to exactly determine error (other than by using arbitrary-precision arithmetic).  But there are techniques to significantly reduce error, e.g. [*Kahan summation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).